# Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\mathrm dx$ diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Show that  integration of $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right|\mathrm dx$$ is equal to infinity.
Is  the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} =1$$  useful here?

Comment: What's the lower limit of the integral?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I edited that last sentence "as is" , though I don't think it makes much sense. The question is if the integral is divergent, which it is due to the absolute value I recall the proof to be somewhere on this site...

Comment: What is the lower limit of the integration the OP is trying to show?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue minus infinity

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is correct? Firstly, it seems strange that you used $n\to \infty$ instead of $x\to \infty$. Secondly, even if it was $x\to \infty$: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=0$$ However, it is true that: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$$

Comment: @Himanshu Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

To show that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,dx$ diverges, we proceed as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-N\pi}^{N\pi}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,dx&=2\sum_{n=1}^N\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,dx\\\\
&\ge 2\sum_{n=+1}^N \frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} |\sin(x)|\,dx\\\\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2}{n\pi}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since the harmonic series diverges, the integral of interest does likewise.

Comment: @Himanshu Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right|\mathrm dx=2\int_0^{+\infty}\left |\frac{\sin x}{x}\right| dx=2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{x} dx$$
Since $\forall x\in[0,+\infty[\,$, $\,\sin x \in [0,1]$, you have $|\sin x|\ge\sin^2x$. Whence, you obtain:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{x} dx \ge\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x} dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2x}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{2x}-\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\cos 2x}{2x} dx $$
Now, the first integral is divergent, but the second is convergent. Therefore
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right|\mathrm dx$$
is divergent.

Comment: Great answer! At the first line the way to used the fact that we are on the positive real line was sneaky :)

Comment: @KamalSaleh appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\mathcal{A}=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}:|\sin x| \ge  \frac{1}{2} \right\}  \subset \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left[ \pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6} , \pi n+ \frac{5 \pi }{6}\right]$$ then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|  \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \text{d}x   \ge  \int_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}\left|  \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \text{d}x  \ge  \int_{\mathcal{A}}\left|  \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \text{d}x  \ge   \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathcal{A}}  \frac{1}{x}\text{d}x  \ge   \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \int_{\pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6}}^{\pi n+ \frac{5\pi }{6}}  \frac{1}{x}\text{d}x  $$
but
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \int_{\pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6}}^{\pi n+ \frac{5\pi }{6}}  \frac{1}{x}\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \ln \left(  \frac{\pi n+ \frac{5\pi }{6}}{\pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6}} \right)$$

and $$\ln \left(  \frac{\pi n+ \frac{5\pi }{6}}{\pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6}} \right)\sim \frac{\pi}{\pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6}}$$

and $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\pi}{\pi n+ \frac{\pi }{6}}$$

is divergent so the integral too.